# Kohana 3: Prevent a controller action which renders a sub-view from rendering if not called from approved controller

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana-3, hmvc

Let's say I have the domain www.example.com

It has a default controller called 'account'.

This controller is based on a template, and creates a view using it's data, and the result of a couple of other controller's renderings.

Let's call the other controllers, 'game', and 'stats'.

These 'sub-controllers' call View::factory with their own model data, and then the whole thing is rendered for the user.

I don't want people to be able to enter in to the browser www.example.com/game or www.example.com/stats and see the sub-controller's views rendered without the template of the main 'account' controller template.

What's the best way to do this, or adjust my structure to do it.

Comment: You don't want them to go to /game or /stats at all? I'm still at Kohana2 but I suppose setting a route for /game to call /account should work in 3 too

Comment: I'm learning Kohana, and HMVC, so there are a lot of these simple problems that I'm running into, as I get my head around the core concepts.  What I'm realizing is that I will create a Controller Template that supports this and a few other simple features that most of my sub-controllers use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analize if your request main or its just a subrequest:

```
public function before()
{
   parent::before();
   if ($this->request === Request::instance()) 
   {
       // its a main request, throw an exception or redirect
   }
   else
   {
      // ok
   }
}
```

But if you want to use Ajax calls to update some blocks, you should add `Request::$is_ajax` check.

Answer (score 0):

http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=routing:differ_request_for_internal_and_external